# LTXtable space to text

Tags: spacing, ltxtable

I would like to include a long table into my document which crosses several pages. That’s why I use `ltxtable`. The table looks good to me but unfortunately there is a bigger space to the headline compared to the normal text. 
How can I adjust the space to the same size?
This is my first post in a forum. I hope I did it right.
Thank you in advance

Here is the example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{ltxtable, tabularx, longtable} 
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{filecontents}{tabeller}
\begin{longtable}{@{}L{6cm}Z@{}}
Text & Text\\
Text & Text\\
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\subsection{Caption number 1 }
\LTXtable{\textwidth}{tabeller} 



\subsection{Caption number 2 with smaler space to text}
This is text much closer to the caption.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `\LTpre` to 0pt or whatever you like

```
\begin{filecontents}{tabeller}
\LTpre=0pt  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{longtable}{@{}L{6cm}Z@{}}
Text & Text\\
Text & Text\\
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems to be the right command. But if I choose \LTpre=0pt the space is too small now. How do I find out the standard space between subsection and text?

Comment: That depends on the used documentclass what it defines for the section/subsection command.